# Internationalization Spring Hibernate Validation UTF8

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, hibernate-validator

I am trying use internationalization with Hibernate validator and Spring

I found that post which is similar to my problem, however even with those configurations it does not work

My Spring I18n configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class I18nConfig {

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(){

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());

    return factory;
}

}
```

My parent pom configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven-checkstyle.version>2.12.1</maven-checkstyle.version>
    <maven-cobertura.version>2.6</maven-cobertura.version>
    <maven-compiler.version>3.1</maven-compiler.version>
    <maven-enforcer.version>1.3.1</maven-enforcer.version>
    <maven-findbugs.version>3.0.0</maven-findbugs.version>
    <maven-javadoc.version>2.9.1</maven-javadoc.version>
    <maven-jxr.version>2.3</maven-jxr.version>
    <maven-pmd.version>3.2</maven-pmd.version>
    <maven-sonar.version>2.4</maven-sonar.version>
    <maven-surefire.version>2.17</maven-surefire.version>
    <maven-taglist.version>2.4</maven-taglist.version>
    <maven-versions.version>2.1</maven-versions.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-findbugs.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Enables analysis which takes more memory but finds more bugs. If 
                    you run out of memory, changes the value of the effort element to 'low'. -->
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <!-- Reports all bugs (other values are medium and max) -->
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <!-- Produces XML report -->
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <!-- Configures the directory in which the XML report is created -->
                <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-checkstyle.version}</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-cobertura.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-javadoc.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jxr.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-pmd.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-versions.version}</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>dependency-updates-report</report>
                        <report>plugin-updates-report</report>
                        <report>property-updates-report</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-taglist.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-checkstyle.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-enforcer.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>1.7</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Usage mvn sonar:sonar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-sonar.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>project-core</module>
</modules>
```

My project POM

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>onceuponatime</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-core</artifactId>
<name>project-core</name>
<url>http://company.com.br</url>

<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.3</aspectj.version>
    <embedmongo.version>1.46.1</embedmongo.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.1.2.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <javax.el.version>2.2.4</javax.el.version>
    <jodatime.version>2.4</jodatime.version>
    <mongodriver.version>2.12.3</mongodriver.version>
    <morphia.version>0.108</morphia.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>${embedmongo.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
       <version>${javax.el.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
       <version>${javax.el.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${jodatime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <version>${mongodriver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>${morphia.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My portuguese property file has characters such as "í" and "á".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with Resource Bundle Editor, which in Eclipse Juno need be update. http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-rbe/discussion/442487/thread/cbf95f31/

Answer (score 0):

add this code to web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This is not a web project. Actually, this is the core part of project which will be consume be mobile part

Comment: Good luck with your project